# Can't start emulator for AVD

Tags: android, xamarin.android, emulation

I trying to star an emulator for Avd and I'm getting this message: 
[6012]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\y037787.android\avd\Teste.avd/snapshots.img.default-boot.ini for reading. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: The easiest way to "fix" any emulator is to delete it and create a new one based on the same config.

Comment: Are you trying to start an android emulator on virtual device? If so, I don't think a emulator can run on AVD. If not, which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set new directory for avd.